# retrieve specific fields of a sharepoint list using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to retrieve some(not all) of the fields of a sharepoint list irrespective of the list view using javascript.

Comment: DO you want to retrieve list item field values or List properties?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Include and specify the column names when you load the items, see the code below. This will only retrieve only Title

```
function retrieveSpecificListProperties(siteUrl) {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.list= oWebsite.get_lists(listName);

clientContext.load(list, 'Include(Title, Id)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);}
```

2. Other way is when you write your CAML query, add viewfields to your query like 
   `<ViewFields>
       <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
       <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
   </ViewFields>`